# Can I exit Malaysia after the end of the Visa Waiver Program (eNTRI)?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, malaysia

I am an Indian national planning to travel to Malaysia for 10 days at the end of December. According to this link [eNTRI for Indians](https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/FAQ/PDF/FAQ/T&C/eNTRI/eNTRI_India_Nationals_en.pdf?version=1.3/), eNTRI is a Visa waiver program for Indian citizens thats effective until 31st December, 2018.

SInce the Visa waiver program ends on 31st December, can I leave the country (without any legal implications) after 31st Dec, if I arrive using the eNTRI note.

Comment: The T&C you link to do not specifically say so, but I don’t see this as any different to holding a visa that expires on 31 Dec. That is, you may use eNTRI to enter for up to 10 days but must exit on or before 31 Dec unless you hold the appropriate visa (if you need one). Others with better knowledge may diasagree.

Comment: @Traveller That's what I am confused about. The T&C say that the eNTRI note is valid for 3 months from date of application. So, hypothetically, if I apply on 25th December, does the visa stay valid till 3 months from that date, or does it expire on 31st December

Comment: @Prada 1) eNTRI is like a US ESTA: it allows one to fly to Malaysia and request entry, but does not guarantee entry, which is up to the Malaysian Immigration Officer at the border. The T&C says an eNTRI entry is for one entry only, 15 days maximum. Your wording "...does the visa stay valid..." is inapposite. 2) The T&Cs  do not state whether the eNTRI expiration date of December 31, 2019, is the date by which any eNTRI visitors must depart Malaysia, or is only the date after which eNTRI notes will not be issued. I have no idea what the answer might be.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted the support channel for eNTRI and confirmed that the eNTRIs will have the validity after 31 December 2019.

It's mentioned in website that the **applications** are open till December. The already issued visa will remain valid, as it's not specified.

As long as you satisfies all criteria for admission, you will be admitted.

1. eNTRI
2. Flight tickets (check the condition of flights carefully).
3. Return ticket.
4. Proof of stay.
5. Proof of funds.

Chat transcript from Support channel.

```
Anas: Hello Anish, my name is Anas, how may I help you?
Anish: eNTRI program will end on december, right?
Anish: If I get an eNTRI on say, november 15, can I use it till Jan 15 ?
Anish: Or the validity will be only within December ?
Anas: eNTRI is available for Indian and Chinese Nationals until the 31st December, 2019. You can apply for your eNTRI application before the 31st December, if you wish to travel with an eNTRI in 2020.
Anas: ** with an eNTRI Note
Anish: So, if I applied and got approved an eNTRI on December, is it ok if I travel on January?
Anas: Yes.
Anas: The validity period of your eNTRI Note is 3 months, from the eNTRI issued date.
Anish: Thank you.
```

Comment: @MarkMayo The website is linked in the original question. The text does not, however, support Anish Sheela's statement that "applications are open till [sic] December." The text states, rather, that "the _program_ will be effective until December 31, 2019." While it seems very likely that no eNTRI applications will be received (or Notes issued) after that date, the statement doesn't address the validity or use after December 31 of eNTRI Notes issued before December 31. This vagueness is why we're nattering about what the text means. I downvoted this answer.

Comment: @David I have contacted the support channel for eNTRI and confirmed that the eNTRIs will have the validity after 31 December 2019.

Comment: Added the chat transcript